# How could this code be re-written where the loop does not continuously run after another letter in the alphabet?

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I need to create a function, `lettersAfter()`, that accepts three arguments:

- `haystack`: The string to be searched
- `needle`: A character to search for.
- `limit`: The number of letters after the character to return

`lettersAfter()` should return the letters following the first found occurrence of the search character.  The letters returned should be limited to the number of the third argument.

For example:

```
lettersAfter('hello', 'e', 2); // => 'll'
lettersAfter('hello', 'h', 1); // => 'e'
lettersAfter('indefatigable', 'a', 4); // => 'tiga'
```

This is my code:

```js
function lettersAfter(haystack, needle, limit) {
  let letters = ''
  for (i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
    if (needle === haystack[i]) {
      for (j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
        letters += haystack[i + j + 1];
      }
    }
  }
  return letters;
}

console.log(lettersAfter('Bobthebuilder', 'b', 5));
```

According to the prompt, the code should return `'thebu'`, but it ends up returning `'thebuuilde'`. Any advice?

Comment: If either of the answers below solved your issue, then consider marking the one that best helped you as correct. This would help as an indication to others and help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `indexOf` to find your 'needle' and use the found index (if there is one) and the limit to determine a `substring` to return. In the code below, indexOf is used to find the index and 1 is added to this index because we want the letters after `needle`. Then we check to see if `firstIndex > 0` because indexOf returns -1 if no index was found, but since we added 1 this would now be 0. If the condition is true, take a substring from firstIndex and check if the remaining length is less than the limit. I added a return statement for the condition being false to indicate that no index was found.

NOTE: If the `needle` can be more than 1 letter/character, you would need to change `+1` to `+needle.length` when assigning a value to `firstIndex`.

```js
function lettersAfter(haystack, needle, limit) {
  let firstIndex;
  if ((firstIndex = haystack.indexOf(needle) + 1) > 0) {
    return haystack.substring(firstIndex, 
      haystack.length - firstIndex < limit 
      ? haystack.length 
      : (firstIndex + limit));
  } else {
    return `Needle '${needle}' could not be found!`;
  }
}

console.log(lettersAfter('Bobthebuilder', 'b', 5))
```

Comment: The way you're declaring `firstIndex` will make it a global variable (or modify a global variable) because you aren't using `let`, `const`, or `var`, which is a pretty bad idea. Instead, you should declare `firstIndex` inside the function before you use it.

Comment: @MichaelM. Fair point, I have changed my answer to reflect.

Comment: For the clearer error checking, +1 (didn't think of that in my own answer). It makes it a bit longer, but it should run just as fast, so it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this without having to use the break method is to utilize a [while loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) nested in a for loop. See the example below:

```js
let haystack = '';
let needle = '';
let limit;
function lettersAfter(haystack, needle, limit)
{let result ='';
for (i=0; i<haystack.length; i++) {
    if (needle===haystack[i]) {
        let j=0; while (j<limit){j++; result += haystack[i+j];
        }
        return result;
    }
    
}}

console.log(lettersAfter('Bobthebuilder', 'b', 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that after the character is found the first time, the loop keeps going and will add more to `letters` if the same character is found a second time. To fix this, `break` out of the loop after you find it the first time:

```js
function lettersAfter(haystack, needle, limit) {
  let letters = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
    if (needle === haystack[i]) {
      for (let j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
        letters += haystack[i + j + 1];
      }
      break; // break out of the loop after first occurance is found
    }
  }
  return letters;
}

console.log(lettersAfter('Bobthebuilder', 'b', 5));
```

However, in the real world, it's better to just use the built-in functions `.indexOf()` and `.substring()`. To replicate returning an empty string if there is no match, just check if `.indexOf()` returns `-1`:

```js
function lettersAfter(haystack, needle, limit) {
  const index = haystack.indexOf(needle);
  if (index == -1) return '';
  return haystack.substring(index+1, index+limit+1);
}

console.log(lettersAfter('Bobthebuilder', 'b', 5));
```

Comment: Currently, if a value is passed for `needle` that doesn't exist in the `haystack` string (`'z'` for example), the second snippet will simply print a substring starting from the beginning of the string. Not sure what the OP might desire in this scenario, but presumably you would either want to print nothing or some form of error message.

Comment: @CalvinP. Thanks for the catch! I edited my answer to replicate the how the first method behaves by returning an empty string in that case.